# Проблема с выводом в консоль

Tags: java, консоль

Знакомый говорит, что, возможно, это связано с кодировкой ASCII. Два вопроса: почему именно возникает такая ситуация и можно ли это исправить?

[image]

Comment: Я так и не понял вопроса... На скриншоте ничего криминального не узрел

Comment: Ну так да, всё правильно. Вы прочли символ '1' с терминала и вывели его как число..

Comment: для того чтобы считать информацию с консоли лучше использовать класс  

    Scanner

Answer (score 1):

Раскрывая комментарий [@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m), вы читаете символ из консоли, но сохраняете его не как символ, а как код этого символа, например, как код ASCII. А соответственно выводиться оно будет функцией `System.out.print(int i);` вместо `System.out.print(char c);`

Чтобы этого избежать либо сохраняйте каким-то образом символ, как символ, либо выводите, используя, например, приведение типов.

Answer (score 1):

Есть цикл очень хороших статей по этой проблеме. 
[Вавилонское столпотворение.](http://www.skipy.ru/technics.html#io)

Конкретно вам должна помочь вот [эта статья](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/encodings_console_comp.html).

Comment: помогла идея об использовании Scanner, всем спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input value of x: ");
    int x=n.nextInt();
```

Такое должно сработать

Comment: А прочесть четыре сообщения слабо? Ведь написно же, что вопрос разрешён. Сам автор написал.